# django-jsignature on a modal not showing until I change the screen size

Tags: javascript, django

I'm trying to get a Django-signature form into a modal but the pad were to sign isn't loading.
The modal and the rest of the form, buttons and whatnot are there and fine.

If I then change the size screen, either changing the actual size of the browser or by entering responsive design mode/toggle device toolbar on web developer tools, the pad will appear and work fine.

Its probably a size/resize issue with the library but I seem to get stuck here.

PS. all is fine if don't use modal but a full html page instead.

The code:

test.html :
(loading the modal with a btn call to htmx)

```
<button 
    type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
    hx-get="{% url 'tools:test_signature' %}"
    hx-target="#modal-fullscreen-signature-content"
    hx-trigger="click">

    Launch signature
 </button>
```

view.py :
(not checking for post or anything, its juts a test to make the signature work)

```
def test_signature(request):
    signform = forms.SignatureForm()
    context = {'signform': signform,}
    return render(request, 'tools/test_signature.html', context)
```

forms.py:

```
from jsignature.widgets import JSignatureWidget

class SignatureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Signature
        fields = "__all__"
```

modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-fullscreen-signature" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-fullscreen-signature-content">
        </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
           <button id="save_btn" hx-post="{% url 'tools:test_signature' %}" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(and some js to show up the modal.)

```
const modal_fullscreen_signature = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("modal-fullscreen-signature"))
  
htmx.on("htmx:afterSwap", (e) => {
// Response targeting #dialog => show the modal
    console.log(e.detail.target.id)
    if (e.detail.target.id == "modal-fullscreen-signature-content") {
        modal_fullscreen_signature.show()
    }
})
```

If anybody has a good idea, I appreciate the help.
Thanks,

I tried to force a resize of the window and of the form upon modal loading but all seems to fail.